# Why do my import statements give error in VS code while working in PyCharme?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm writing an Assembler in Python and I'm trying to switch to VS code for my development task since I enjoy really much its simplicity. After loosing an afternoon trying to figure out why my import statements give error, I tried to open the same project in PyCharm and everything went fine.
The structure of my project:

```
/assembler
  /src
   __init__.py
   code.py
   main.py
   parser.py
   symbol_table.py
```

So I ended up losing a lot of time on Python 3.6 documentation to figure out what I was doing wrong, and then after discovering that the code was ok I just couldn't find anything to determine what in my configuration caused the issue, not even on VSCode issues questions.
This is my simple main() function that should import the classes within the other modules in the same package.

```
from src.parser import Parser
from src.code import Code
from src.symbol_table import SymbolTable


def main():
    parser = Parser()
    code = Code()
    symbol_table = SymbolTable()

    parser.has_more_commands()


main()
```

It should just print something on the screen to acknowledge that the import went fine, instead i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/miche/Desktop/NAND2TETRIS/projects/06/assembler/src/main.py", line 1, in 
    from src.parser import Parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Has anyone had my same issue with VSCode and could tell me what's wrong with my configuration or statements?

Answer (score 0):

I don know exactly the problem in Windows VS Code but maybe the relative path is wrong. I had an similar problem on macOS.

In /assembler/src/__init__.py try:

```
from .parser import Parser
from .code import Code
from .symbol_table import SymbolTable
```

and in your main.py try:

```
from .src import Parser, Code, SymbolTable
```